# AFL stats, dropbox boxes, event fire

Tags: javascript, vba, internet-explorer, dropdownbox

I haven't done much VBA interaction with IE and am doing this to learn as much as I can. So any help/tips or tricks/better ways to do this would be greatly appreciated. I have already spend a huge amount of time getting to where I am now and am using Excel Forum as a last resource, so I'm sincerely asking for help.

Please see the following website: http://www.afl.com.au/stats

Problem 1: I am able to get vba to select "SEASON" from the dropdown boxes But the data stays the same (very wrong). I think I am missing an .fireEvent or run Function? or a "reload page"?

Problem 2: I an unable to find any unique IDs for selecting "ROUND", So I am unable to manipulate this for TEAMS or PLAYERS. (I haven't a clue how to work around this)

Problem 3: Once I am able to manipulate "SEASON", "PLAYERS" and "ROUND", I am interested in manipulating "Advanced Options" (I haven't looked at this yet)
Problem 4: After "Advanced Options" I want to extract the data to excel. (I haven't looked at this yet)

```
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.navigate "http://www.afl.com.au/stats"
IE.Visible = True
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE And Not IE.Busy

IE.document.getElementById("stats_tab").getElementsByTagName("a")(1).Click
'clicks on "players" box

IE.document.getElementById("stats-team-stats").getElementsByTagName("option")(0).removeAttribute("selected") = "true"
IE.document.getElementById("stats-team-stats").getElementsByTagName("option")(2).setAttribute("selected") = "true"
'dropdown box un-selects 2017 and then selects 2015 team stats, but data for 2015 does not load!!


IE.document.getElementById("stats-player-stats").getElementsByTagName("option")(0).removeAttribute("selected") = "true"
IE.document.getElementById("stats-player-stats").getElementsByTagName("option")(2).setAttribute("selected") = "true"
'dropdown box un-selects 2017 and then selects 2015 team stats, but data for 2015 does not load!!
```

Thanks guys!

Jimmy

Comment: Surely there's an API that will expose this data more readily than this method? Or does it have to be VBA / IE for some reason?

Comment: Hi Lucas. What's an API? I've looked everywhere and I can't find a better site that gives the data. I only have knowledge in VBA/IE and this is just me trying to practice and get better at my skills. I am genuinely stuck. so any help at all would be great. See [link](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1180012-afl-stats-manipulating-dropdown-boxes-fireevent.html#post4619993)

Comment: An API is what the AFL used to use to share its data with developers before it appears that  something called Champion Data bought the rights and now charges a small fortune for access. Grrr. Have a look on the Whirlpool forums, there are some guys over there trying to do something similar for their tipping comps. FWIW, you're better off manipulating a dropdown by its selected index: `IE.document.getElementById("stats-player-stats").selectedIndex=4;`

Comment: Still working on this, Learning python at the moment to see if I can find a way to web-scrap the information.